# How to rename a lot of files in bash shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, perl, rename

Sorry for the question. I searched the internet a lot, but couldn't find an answer which worked (though there were a lot of suggestions).

So, I want to rename A LOT of files. Writing all file names is not an option.
The files are named like this:

`HAUPT_SIA_039.MR.NEUROPSYCHOLOGIE_LOGIN.0003.0001.2014.03.28.14.49.59.511530.47117493.IMA`

the beginning is always the same and also the .IMA The long number is not the same for all files. I have to change the 039 into 036_2, for all files. The rest should stay the same.

I tried all of the following commands (plus several others), but it didn't do anything:

```
cd my_directory

rename 's/\w039_2\w/\w036_2\w/g' * 

rename ?039_2? ?036_2? ?0_39_2?.IMA

rename 's/?039_2?/?036_2?/' ?039_2?.IMA

rename 's/\w039_2\w/\w036_2\w/' ?039_2?.IMA
```

Perl is installed at the linux system (but I'm not sure how to call it... because if I open a perl terminal it doesn't do anything).

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in * ; do mv $file $(echo $file | sed 's/_039/_036_2') ; done
```

Explanation:

```
for file in * ; do _______ ; done
```

bash will perform shell expansion on `*` to list every file in the working directory.  For each of these files, this command structure will set the variable `file` to be equal to the file name and run the command between `; do` and `; done`

```
mv $file _______
```

`mv` is the traditional way to rename files in unix/linux.  It will rename `file` to `_______`

```
echo $file | sed 's/_039/_036_2'
```

`echo $file | sed` will simply send "`file`" to the stdin of `sed`, where `sed` will substitute "_039" for "_036_2"

Altogether:  for every file in the current directory, rename the file, substituting "_039" for "_036_2"

Comment: Or `mv "$file" "${file/_039/_036_2}"`

Answer (score 1):

Your regexp is messed up, here is one that should work.

`rename 's/HAUPT_SIA_039[.]\(.*\)/HAUPT_SIA_039_2.\1/g' HAUPT_SIA*.IMA`

You are using the correct tool, no need for find unless you have sub-directories.

---

Note about regexp in sed and rename.

The format is `sXsearch_patternXreplace_patternXoptions` (`X` can be any character).
searchPattern is what you are looking to replace, there for what already exists, not what you are replacing with.

`-w` is a single word, and can only be in search_pattern.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Unfortunately I still have problems (as you see, I don't know shell, but I have to do the renaming for another task which I will do after that). So, when I try your suggestion it doesn't do anything. The 'rename' does exist. I checked with 'info rename'.

Comment: check `less $(which rename)` it should be written by  Robin Barker, Larry Wall's

Answer (score 0):

find . -name "*039*" | rename 's/039/036_2/g'

Comment: Thank you! I tried it, but the shell says: "Aufrug: rename von nach Dateien..." and doesn't do anything. I think the stuff the shell sais can be translated as "Call: rename from to data"

Answer (score 0):

Loop all files with the "HAUPT_..." prefix, then rename using shell substring `${f:15}` returns the string from the 15th char of the file name, appended to the `HAUPT_...` prefix.

```
for f in "HAUPT_SIA_039*" ; do  mv $f "HAUPT_SIA_036_2${f:15}"; done
```

**EDIT**
- It appears that the directory with all the files also contains sub-directories with the same HAUPT... prefix. In that case use the `find` command to first filter only the files and not directories.

```
find . -type f -name "HAUPT_SIA_039*" | while read f; do mv $f "HAUPT_SIA_036_2${f:15}"; done
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately the shell complaints that "HAUPT_SIA_036_2" is no directory. Should I move the files in a new directory and delete the old one?

Comment: Yes, that would be one way to fix the problem (as long as it's just the files that are moved), or see my edit.